# Error when installing nfs-kernel-server

Tags: 11.04, server, package-management

I continue to get this error when trying to install following:

```
root@127:/home/gordon# sudo apt-get install nfs-kernel-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libnfsidmap2 librpcsecgss3 nfs-common portmap
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libnfsidmap2 librpcsecgss3 nfs-common nfs-kernel-server portmap
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/367 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,491 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously deselected package libnfsidmap2.
(Reading database ... 252530 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking libnfsidmap2 (from .../libnfsidmap2_0.23-2_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 fork failed: Cannot allocate memory
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
root@127:/home/gordon#
```

Is it a package problem or a memory problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's a memory problem.  the system cannot allocate memory for the unpacking process for `libnfsidmap2`, likely because there is no extra memory available.  You will need to install more memory on the system or allocate more memory to the vm (if its a VM) to unpack the file you are installing.